# Bundle Product - Discount if ALL items in bundle are selected

Tags: magento-1.9, price, bundled-product

I would like to discount the price of a bundle product by 15% if the customer orders all the products in the bundle.  I don't want to use the 'Special Price' option because I want all the simple products in the bundle to show their full price; if they are all selected, however, I want the total price to be discounted by 15%.

I think I could do the frontend price display part easily enough with javascript, but what would be the proper way to check if the bundle is full and set the corresponding price for the shopping cart in the backend?